# This same code not working in function. (generate EAN8)

Tags: php, function, while-loop

I write a simple code to generate EAN8 code and check did record exist in database. When i use just code it's working perfect but when i try to change transform it for a function i have only blank page.
This code working

```
do{
$number = rand(1,9999999);
$number = str_pad($number, 7, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);

$sum = ($number[0] * 3) +($number[1] * 1) + ($number[2] * 3) + ($number[3] * 1) + ($number[4] * 3) + ($number[5] * 1) + ($number[6] * 3);
$control = 10 - ($sum%10);
$ean8 = $number.$control;



        $ean8 = substr($ean8, 0,8);
        $db->where('numberCard',$ean8);
        $user = $db->getOne('user');

}
while($db->count !== 0);

echo $ean8;
```

and this same code past in function return blank page

```
function generateEan(){
do{
    $number = rand(1,9999999);
    $number = str_pad($number, 7, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);

    $sum = ($number[0] * 3) +($number[1] * 1) + ($number[2] * 3) + ($number[3] * 1) + ($number[4] * 3) + ($number[5] * 1) + ($number[6] * 3);
    $control = 10 - ($sum%10);
    $ean8 = $number.$control;



            $ean8 = substr($ean8, 0,8);
            $db->where('numberCard',$ean8);
            $user = $db->getOne('user');

    }
while($db->count !== 0);

return $ean8;
}

echo generateEan();
```

Where is the problem ? Where i have made mistake? Please, help me and have a nice night

Answer (score 0):

inside the scope of generateEan function, exists $db ?

maybe you can do a simple function and test if it exists

Comment: Oh my god, thank you. I forgot add global $db; on the top of function. Seriously thanks!!! have a nice night

Comment: you're welcome. maybe can pass $db by paramenter, is more recomended than use global